# How to Add a Div and text in side the div in aspx using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Add a Div and text inside a div in .aspx file using C#. 
I want to add a textbox for typing comment or query and a button to post that text/query.
to the server.
After redirect that page should get data from DB and Show on that page.
same as(all Forms)
like stackoverflow, we type Question, and submit it, can show it

Answer (score 1):

Taken from code project site -  To create a div inside a div (By the way it works if you are using asp.net)

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl Panel = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    Panel.ID = "panel1";
    Panel.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "White");
    Panel.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "680px");
    Panel.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "660px");
    Panel.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "Black");
    Panel.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "Groove");
    Panel.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "2px");
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    div.ID = "panel12";
    div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "White");
    div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "70px");
    div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
    div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "Black");
    div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "Groove");
    div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "2px");
    this.Controls.Add(Panel);
    Panel.Controls.Add(div);
```